# Wrong query is being sent, email IS NULL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to add a new User to an existing DB. Whenever I use the signup form for this, it results in a lookup for an user with the email NULL.

```
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" IS NULL LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  rollback transaction
```

Looking at the Server Log, it actually states the valid Email-address:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"epYmQoIfibeimZEFYo5MdSIqjJM3sLZgTtj79rMpvyQ=", "user"=>
 {"name"=>"Herp Derp", "email"=>"lang.martin@herpderp.de", "password"=>"[FILTERED]",      
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create User"}
```

The user.rb looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }


  validates :name, presence: true,
                   length: {maximum: 40}

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true,
          format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
          uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  validates :password, length: {minimum: 6}
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
end
```

And the entry form following: (Using Formtastic)

```
%h1 Sign Up
%div.row
  %div.span6.offset3
    = semantic_form_for @user do |f|
      = f.inputs do
        = f.input :name
        = f.input :email
        = f.input :password
        = f.input :password_confirmation
        = f.action :submit
```

user_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:users])
    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to create a new user in the rails console (rails s)?

Comment: in your before_save, try this  before_save { |user| user.email = self.email.downcase }          adding "self" before email.downcase

Comment: @Quantaqa if you found the solution don't forget to add the answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the error:

```
def create
   @user = User.new(params[:users])
  if @user.save
  redirect_to @user
else
  render 'new'
end
```

The params changed to :user and done.

Comment: Martin, can you clarify what you mean by "The params changed to :user and done." Your code looks the same as the original code.